# Linking Me To Wrong Page?

Tags: xampp, localhost

When I type in localhost/index.php into my URL bar it redirects me to this URL: localhost/xampp/. Why is this happening and why is the localhost/index.php link not taking me to the index.php page?

Comment: Is it going to a configuration-type page? Or is it still serving the contents of `index.php`, just with that address?

Comment: This is the page showing up: http://sawmac.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/xampp_page.png

Answer (score 0):

`htdocs` is the folder that XAMPP serves out of. If you look at the contents of `xampp/htdocs/index.php`, which is what `localhost/index.php` would resolve to, you'll see the line `header('Location: '.$uri.'/xampp/');`, which basically redirects your browser to the contents of `xampp/htdocs/xampp`. It will by default search for the `index.php` file if one is not specified in the address, so you end up where your screenshot points.

Make sense?